# Is Azure NSG IP whitelist safe enough?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am now using Azure NSG to only allow trusted IPs to access my backend service hosted on Azure IaaS VMs in my own VNET.

My question is, is IP whitelist strategy safe enough? I am wondering if it is possible that the hacker forge the source IP to be one of the IP in my whitelist so that be able to access my service?

I am not familiar to the hacker techniques, don't know if it is possible...

Comment: There's no real *right* answer to this ( "safe enough" is going to be different  depending on circumstances / app / etc). And there are ways to circumvent IP filtering. But... this type of discussion is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience, suitable NSG rules could help you prevent hacker’s attacks. For your scenario, you add white list in NSG rules. Also, I suggest you enable the useful ports and unnecessary ports on Azure rules (Inbound rules). Please pay attention the priority of NSG rules. **The IP white list NSG rule should be highest priority.** More information about NSG please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg).

Except NSG, I think you had better enable your VM’s Firewall.

Based on my knowledge, there is no absolute security. Appropriate safe strategy could enhance the security of your VMs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no definitive solution when it come to security, NSG are a good approach in the cloud to filter traffic from the internet and within you virtual network, hackers cannot forge private IP address from outside your virtual network, this rules apply to encapsulated traffic within the platform.

If someone gets access to one of your VMs with different methods, then you have to add extra levels of security to prevent additional damage by adding complexity on the process, multiple accounts for different purpose, security schema for isolated traffic, etc.